# In angular 2 how do I hook up my cachebust js files to the app for deploying?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angular

**This is my gulp code for cache busting the js files and it works fine:**

```
gulp.task('getAllJsFiles', function() {
        gulp.src('src/app/**/**/*.js')
            .pipe(cachebust.resources())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('src/app/js/'))
});
```

The problem I have is, how do I now wire up these files so that my app uses them?

I'm using angular and typescript.

Currently the **app.component.js** file becomes: Current the app.component.js file becomes: app.component.e072d853.js as an example.
I'm guessing I would just wire that up?

**Here is my index file stripped down a bit:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/"></base>

    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.e072d853.css">
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- Js libs -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/safariPolyFix.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.src.js"></script>   

    <script>
        System.config({
            transpiler: 'typescript',
            defaultJSExtensions: true,  
            typescriptOptions: {
                emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
            },          
            packages: {
                'angular2-google-maps': {
                  defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });       
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular2_google_maps.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.js"></script>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/firebase/firebaseNew.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body id="container">

    <app></app>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
      //Not sure if I need to do something here??????
      System.import('/app/app.component.js');
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Heres the js part of my gulp file (which works fine):

```
gulp.task('getAllJsFilesAndCacheBust', function() {
        gulp.src('src/app/**/**/*.js')
            .pipe(cachebust.resources())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('src/app/js/'))

});
```

I just need to know how to wire up the app.component.js thats now this: app.component.685d875q.js. I cant seem to get that imported

Comment: you should use gulp-inject to inject those files into your html... pipe the output of cachebust to gulp-inject.. that will do it

Comment: I have that working. My question is how do I wire that up for an angular 2 app in my index file

Comment: i dont see gulp-inject in ur question.. can you post more relevant code from ur gulpfile

Comment: I've added the gulp code above for the cache busting. Which works fine. I dont need to gulp inject, thats not how angular 2 works. I use system to import the app.component.js.